# "He spends twice as much money as I earn" is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, comparisons

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> He spends twice as much money as I earn.

I'm wondering if the first verb (spend) and the second verb (earn) can be different. All the examples of "**N times as much something as**" pattern I found in English grammar text books have the same verbs, or the second verb is omitted as being the same as the first.

Comment: There is nothing whatever wrong with the sentence. The zeugma here can perfectly well yoke two distinct verbs to the same direct object.

Comment: Agreed.  The sentence is grammatically correct.  On a side note, when the second verb is omitted, some people append "do," as in "He earns twice as much money as I **do**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is correct.

There is a common idiom:

*"I've forgotten more about X than you'll ever know."*

As you can see, the verbs are different in this comparison.

**Example**

"Yeah? Well, I've forgotten more about paleontology than you'll ever know." - New Yorker Cartoon
By:  Joseph Mirachi
http://www.condenaststore.com/-sp/Yeah-Well-I-ve-forgotten-more-about-paleontology-than-you-ll-ever-know-New-Yorker-Cartoon-Prints_i8642068_.htm

Comment: Or "[Pronoun] has [verbed] more [anything] than [somebody] has had hot dinners"